# Binding a mat-select to an onOpen event

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to bind a mat-select to a function which will call java and get the data that has to be shown as options.

However the (onOpen) event doesn't works , to be more accurate the function bound to it is never called.

Does anyone had an issue like this one ?

Here is my code :

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Select Year of the Report" (onOpen)="getData(0)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of this.years">
          {{year}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Here is the function getData:

```
getData(ref: number) {
    console.log('it Works !');
    this.recommendationService.getRecommendationFilters(ref).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.years = data;
      console.log(data.toString())
    });
  }
```

Thank You !

Comment: why dont you use (click) event instead of (onOpen) ?

Comment: the fact is that if I use click I'll need to click 2 times in order to see the data. because the select will be open before the function is called

Answer (score 0):

you'r first problem is that you should remove this. from below line.

```
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of this.years">
```

just write

```
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years">
```

The other problem is that you can use (click) event inside you'r **select** element and it will call only once.

look at [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eceqxg?file=src/app/app.component.html) that I have prepare for you.

As soon as you click on the select element to open it, it will call function just once.

Comment: It doesn't work, the fact is that there is no data in years the first time you click , there is one only after the first time, I need something that if I clicked it will get the data from java and only then open the select

Comment: It's working . I updated my demo . look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bm8obs?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It's still doesn't work I can't understand why I even tried to open and close it manually but doesn't open it... It only opens the second time because the first = no Data, and then if you click only one time it will charge the info of the click before that

Comment: please add whatever you are trying to  stackblitz.com then only I can solve you'r problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
   <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Year of the Report" (change)='getData($event)'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" value= 0>
      {{year}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

in your ts file use below code

```
getData(event: any) {
ref = event.target.value;
console.log('it Works !');
this.recommendationService.getRecommendationFilters(ref).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.years = data;
  console.log(data.toString())
});
```

}

Comment: It doesn't work, the fact is that there is no data in years the first time you click , there is one only after the first time, I need something that if I clicked it will get the data from java and only then open the select –